# Firemonkey Listview & mobile screen orientation in Delphi 11

Tags: listview, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

I am fairly new to the Firemonkey framework after working with VCL for many years so hopefully this question is not too simple.

I am listing Dynamic Listview Items which I update from a database. I have created the position/layout of the text within the Listview Item using design mode . My question is when I change screen orientation from portrait to landscape do I have to manually change the 'X' position of the text items located within my listview and their width so that the full landscape width of the screen is utilized? There appears to be no anchors for dynamically created Listview items. (The text items just have their generic names for the time being.)

I have a pic below of what I am trying to describe. First pic shows deign mode in portrait and second in landscape.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

[Portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25nPL.png)

[Landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u64UK.png)

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your answer. I have looked a little closer after reading your post and you are absolutely correct. I just need to set align to either leading or trailing depending on what edge of screen I want to anchor the text to, I can then read the Listview width property on changing screen orientation to calculate how wide I want the text items etc. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Accessory`, `Detail` and `Text` items have an `Align` property that can take values `Center`, `Leading` or `Trailing`. They are recalculated and adjust their position with changes in the screen orientation.

Additionally some items have a separate property, `TextAlign`, which sets the position for a text within the space of the `Align` result.

Answer (score 0):

i recommended using TListBox then you can custom the TListBoxItem using StyleBook, or you can create design on Design runtime then clone on TListBoxItem.

here tutorial from youtube

[Link Tutoral 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zljD_jWrH_Y&t=170s)

[Link Tutorial 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFnA9tbBrPs&t=778s)